# How to generate 3 unique random numbers and use it as an ID in drupal webform?

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a custom js file in my custom module, which generates a 3-digit ID,

```
function genDigit() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*899+100);
}
```

I would like to add this ID in my webform as follows:

1. When a user opens a webform page in the browser, the js is called from the custom module (assuming the module is active)
2. The generated ID is passed automatically to the webform in a hidden field
3. When submitting the form, the ID is saved as well alongside the other data.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to create 3 unique IDs or do you want an ID which consists of 3 different numbers? E.g. 123 but not 112? Do you have a problem with assigning that generated number to the hidden input field? Do you need help saving the form data? Really not sure where you need help.

Comment: In fact the js function will generate a 3-digit number between 000-999. My issue is how to send this generated number from the function to include it in my webform once a user loads a webform page (in a hidden field for example). The Drupal module used here is Webform module, and my JS is in a custom module.

Comment: The JS approach to add ID in form already sounds wrong!

Comment: @CornelAndreev Can you please suggest a convenient way of doing it?

Comment: @Moushrat when you build a form in Drupal 7, a unique form id is already created by Drupal Core, I don't know what to suggest as I don't know your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#ID_ELEMENT").val(Math.floor(Math.random()*899+100));});','inline');
```

Whereby you put the js in the drupal_add_js function itself, instead of calling an external js file to do so. By the way this function does not generate a unique ID, but can give you an idea how to proceed from here.

But the idea of adding such ID to a webform is indeed curious, as any webform has a unique ID already as @CornelAndreev mentioned earlier. Good luck.